# Initialization of EntityManager class object, how to do it?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have following abstract dao class with me:
I am using `find(Long primaryKey)` method for getting data.
like

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T> {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractDao.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }

    public T find(Long primaryKey) {
        //Here entityManager is null therefore I am getting null pointer exception
        return entityManager.find(entityClass,primaryKey);
    }
}
```

Please suggest some techniques to intitalize `entityManager` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `PersistenceContext` annotation from `EntityManager` and create next abstract method

```
public abstract void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager);
```

In this way you can put next method in the main class

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "HERE YOU HAVE TO PUT NAME OF ENTITY MANAGER FACTORY")
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

and all will be works ;) I have it in my owner `DAO` and all works